# Excel C# event for recalculated cell value

Tags: c#, excel, events

Currently I am listening to cell changed events in Excel via Worksheet.Change.
However this does not react to reevaluated values of cells with formulas.
Microsoft states on [this site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.calculate.aspx) that there is a calculate event in the worksheet class, but I can not find this event. There is only the Calculate() method.

Do you have any suggestions how to listen on reevaluated cells?

Comment: Has someone any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

I managed to find a way to react to cell recalculations:

First one hase to register at the Workbook.SheetCalculate event, because there is no such event at worksheet level.

This event returns the worksheet on which cells have been recalculated. Important note: It does not return the recalculated cells it returns all cells.

From this point on I iterate over these cells and look for formulas and their value.

Registration to get the event:

```
workbook.SheetCalculate += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.WorkbookEvents_SheetCalculateEventHandler(CalculateEvent);
```

Calculate event looks like this:

```
private void CalculateEvent(Object Sh)
{
    if (!(Sh is Workbook))
        return;

    Worksheet s = Sh as Worksheet;
    Range range = s.UsedRange;

    foreach(Range cell in range.Cells)
    {
        string formula = Convert.ToString(cell.Formula);

        if(formula.IndexOf('=') >= 0)
            //Do something
    }
}
```

Hope I can help someone with this.